# Create a SubColumn inside a Column Family in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, super-columns

I have been trying to see if I can have nested columns in a cassandra column family either super or normal.  I have look all over and have not fully seen what I am looking for.

I am wanting to do something like this.

```
 `[{ firstname: "Me", 
     lastname: "Smith",
     HomeAddress: { Street: "1234 Any Place Dr"
                    ,State: "IL"
                    ,zip:  "62024"
                  }
  }]`
```

From the following  post [Create a Cassandra schema for a super column with metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298039/create-a-cassandra-schema-for-a-super-column-with-metadata)

I found something similar but it is not working the way I wanted to.

```
create column family users                           
with comparator = UTF8Type
 and compression_options = { sstable_compression:SnappyCompressor, chunk_length_kb:64}
 and column_metadata = [
  { column_name: FirstName, validation_class : UTF8Type}
  { column_name: LastName, validation_class : UTF8Type},
  { column_name: FavStore, validation_class : IntegerType}
 , { column_type: super, column_name: HomeAddress } 
 ];
```

Here is my code that shows how I created my column family.

It creates it but then if I put the address in like the JSON example above it does not seem to work.

Here is my output when I do a list from the cli.

`RowKey: 646f68616c6c
    => (column=FavStore, value=59580595188280, timestamp=1330696438)
    => (column=Favorites, value=HASH(0x3618bc0), timestamp=1330696438)
    => (column=FirstName, value=Me, timestamp=1330696438)
    => (column=HomeAddress, value=HASH(0x3618b30), timestamp=1330696438)
    => (column=LastName, value=Smith, timestamp=1330696438)`

When I try and pull out the values from Home Address I get nothing.  It appears that it is empty.  I pulled it from some perl code and the Hash tells me that it is blank.

I am wondering if this is even possible and if it is not what is the best approach to add a sub column to a column family.  Or am I just barking up the wrong tree.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to mix normal columns and super columns. Cassandra requires that all columns in a column family are either normal columns or super columns. Instead of trying to use a super column you could do one of the following:

- Split the home address column up into 3 columns: `address_street`, `address_state`, `address_zip`
- Store the components of the address in one column using your favorite serialization format (json, protocol buffers, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I like the Idea of JSON for the Address info.  I will give that a shot.